# catch spider close signal

Tags: python, scrapy

I have three spiders. I need to run two of them, then, when one spider is closed, the last one should be started.

This is how I run my spiders

```
s = get_project_settings()
process = CrawlerProcess(s)
process.crawl(spider1)
process.crawl(spider2)
process.start()
```

I have read the scrapy documentation about Signals, but still can't get it, where in my code can I catch `signals.connect(spider.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)`?